# Prevent rerender of sibling component which initiates a useState in wrapper component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rerender

I am not very experienced with React but I have a very simple Setup.

```
export default function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("still-empty");

  const myFunction = title => {
    setTitle(title);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ComponentA myFunction={myFunction} />
      <br />
      <br />
      <ComponentB title={title} />
    </div>
  );
}



const ComponentA = ({ myFunction }) => {
  console.log("Rendering Component A");

  return (
    <div onClick={() => myFunction(Math.random() * 1000)}> Component A </div>
  );
};

export default ComponentA;


const ComponentB = ({ title }) => {
  return <div> Title : {title}</div>;
};

export default ComponentB;
```

Here is a sandbox to test this: **https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-cookies-g7szr**

See that if you click on "ComponentA", that exact ComponentA gets rerendered (you can see it in console) although no props are changed on this component. This is a simplified example of my real use case. In my real use case, ComponentA is a map where a lot of stuff (zoom, center) 
 will be reset. I want to prevent these resets and also the 1 second it takes for rerendering. Therefor I present this simplified example.

So how do I pass an information from ComponentA to ComponentB, without rerendering ComponentA itself? Thanks for helping out here.

Comment: You are changing the state of the parent component, which re-renders the parent component and its children, i.e ComponentA and ComponentB. If you will regularly being doing stuff like this and don't want any unnecessary re-renders then you should probably look at something like Redux to allow the child components to access state directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I change the state in the parent. But this state variable is not used by ComponentA. So why does it get rerendered? Is there a way around that?

Comment: It doesn't matter that ComponentA is not using the state variable. When you call setState React will mark your parent company as being dirty and will trigger a re-render of it (and thus its sub components, A & B). Even if the value in the state hasn't changed (i.e if you pass it the same value it already has), calling setState will still trigger a re-render.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `useCallback` in Parent so that the function is not created again and again but only on initial render.
use `React.memo` so that when no props are changed the component wont re-render.

**App**

```js
export default function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("still-empty");

  const myFunction = useCallback(title => {
    setTitle(title);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ComponentA myFunction={myFunction} />
      <br />
      <br />
      <ComponentB title={title} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**ComponentA**

```js
import React, { memo } from "react";

const ComponentA = ({ myFunction }) => {
  console.log("Rendering Component A");

  return (
    <div onClick={() => myFunction(Math.random() * 1000)}> Component A </div>
  );
};

export default memo(ComponentA);
```

Working demo is here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-boyd-v7g2t?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works on my real example as well. Thank you so much.